# ifstream fail bit being set unsure why

Tags: c++, ifstream

Maybe seeing the issue would help you all a little:

https://ws.onehub.com/files/nzvrbj4s

Screen Shots:
https://ws.onehub.com/files/9rw3li12
https://ws.onehub.com/files/37ggbfio

This is the demo exe file.

WASD to move the player around
mouse to aim
mouse left click to fire
R to Reload
M to Create a monster (I have one spawn point in the game that spits out 5 monsters 3 alive at a time max on the spawn point)

I am loading monster data in from a file which contains the following:

`Spider_Walk/`

```
12

Spider_Attack/

1

Spider_Die/

9

3

17 32 5  2

28 32 8  1

48 32 15 1
```

I check the file every time I spawn a spider for the data of the hit zones and file paths for the animations.  I do not reload the animations every time due to the resource manager class which prevents multiple animations from being double loaded.  Currently I can spawn many many monsters, but then out of the blue ifstream sets the fail bit on me and I crash.  I am trying to understand why my fail bit is being set.

My output is:

`(1)LOAD FILE IS BAD! FLAGS SET`

```
EOF: 0
BAD: 0
FAIL: 1
FILENAME.c_str(): gfx/Spider/Spider.txt
```

Any advice would be helpful at the moment I am thinking about making a monster info class and putting it in with the resource manager to only load monster data one time.  I just fear this failure is the tip of the iceberg and something much bigger is lurking.

Smallest code chunk that would probably eventually reproduce the issue.

ifstream load_file;

load_file.open(filename.c_str());

if(!load_file.good())allegro_message("(1) LOAD FILE IS BAD! FLAGS SET\n EOF: %i \n BAD: %i \n FAIL: %i \n FILENAME.c_str(): %s", load_file.eof(), load_file.bad(), load_file.fail(), filename.c_str());

FULL CONSTRUCTOR CODE FOLLOWS:

`Monster::Monster(string filename,Resource_Manager *nrm)`

```
{

    rm = nrm;
    //Class initalizations
    Draw_Hit_Zones = true;
    Draw_Health_Bar = true;
    last_zone_hit = -1;
    Dieing = false;
    Time_Of_Death = 0;

    cur_state = 0;
    MAGIC = NULL;
    delay = 100;
    cur_frame = 0;
    dr = 0;
    r = 0;
    Move_Speed = 10;
    timer = clock();

    Max_Hit_Points = 50;
    Cur_Hit_Points = Max_Hit_Points;
    //end class initalizations

    stringstream ss;
    string root_path = filename.substr(0,filename.find_last_of("/\\")+1);     // /gfx/Spider/

    string load_image_path;
    string load_mask_path;

    string temp;

    ifstream load_file;
    load_file.open(filename.c_str());
    if(!load_file.good())allegro_message("(1) LOAD FILE IS BAD! FLAGS SET\n EOF: %i \n BAD: %i \n FAIL: %i \n FILENAME.c_str(): %s", load_file.eof(),load_file.bad(),load_file.fail(),filename.c_str());
    load_file>>temp>>W_num_frames;
    W_ANI.assign(root_path);
    W_ANI.append(temp);

    load_file>>temp>>A_num_frames;
    A_ANI.assign(root_path);
    A_ANI.append(temp);

    load_file>>temp>>D_num_frames;
    D_ANI.assign(root_path);
    D_ANI.append(temp);

    if(!load_file.good())allegro_message("(2)LOAD FILE IS BAD! FLAGS SET\n EOF: %i \n BAD: %i \n FAIL: %i", load_file.eof(),load_file.bad(),load_file.fail());

    rm->Load_Sprite(W_ANI,W_ANI);
    rm->Load_Sprite(A_ANI,A_ANI);
    rm->Load_Sprite(D_ANI,D_ANI);

    magic_number = (int)ceil(sqrt(rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->w*rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->w + rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->h*rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->h));

    load_file>>num_col;

    Hit_Zones = new C_Circ*[num_col];
    multipliers = new int[num_col];
    int cx,cy,cr;
    for(int lcv = 0;lcv < num_col;lcv++)
    {
        load_file>>cx>>cy>>cr>>multipliers[lcv];
        Hit_Zones[lcv] = new C_Circ(cx+(magic_number-rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->w)/2,cy+(magic_number-rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->h)/2,cr);
    }
    Master_Hit_Zone = new C_Rect(x - (rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->w/2),y - (rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->h/2),rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->w,rm->Get_Sprite(W_ANI,0)->h);
    load_file.close();
}
```

Comment: This is too much code. You should try reducing your code sample to the smallest amount of code that still produces the problem. You'll get a lot more help from Stack Overflow and you may even find the solution yourself in the process.

Comment: fstream fails when opening a file.  The file exists, the program can access it just fine the first say 50 or 60 times then it just fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's failing at the open.  When you say spawn, I'm assuming you mean different threads, not new processes.  I suspect you are running out of file descriptors, as there is a limit to the number of open files a given process may have.

When an open fails it sets the global value ERRNO.  You can either get C++ fancy with it (using strerror(errno)) , or just use perror() to see whether this was the issue.

Comment: Actually not even threads in terms of gaming spawn means creating a monster.  Single threaded program, but I will have to keep this in mind since on a multiplayer side of this game I will be using multithreading and that could potentially be an issue.

Comment: But the point is you're not using multiple processes, and you are likely running out of file descriptors.

Comment: I do not use multiple processes in this program not at the moment.  One thread one process.  Wait I misread that.... If I close the File descriptor via load_file.close() every time how would I run out?

Comment: Your code may not be multi-threaded but the game framework Allegro might be: http://alleg.sourceforge.net/stabledocs/en/build/msvc.html refers to linking the multi-threaded DLL version of MSVCRT which strongly hints it uses threads in some manner.

Comment: Well he was right I managed to get it to tell me I have too many open files... doesn't the fstream function close() close the file descriptor?  If the case was too many open files I would not be able to have 100 different monster files according to that theory even if I close() them every time I am done.

Comment: I vaguely recall something about file descriptors not getting recycled immediately.  Is there a reason all of these guys need to read the same file, instead of just having one initialization read the file and put the contents where everyone else can copy it from?

Comment: Since I have only have 1 monster type at the moment I could probably load it into the resource manager class.  In the future though(hopefully near) I will have many more monster types, but I might still be able to parse everything into my resource manager class.  This leaves me with the thought that it is possible that I may need to not load too many monsters at one time.  What is the delay on the recycling time?